# How do I cut seconds into minute intervals?

Tags: r

My data is arranged as below:

```
Data <- data.frame(Seconds = c(4, 33, 46, 64, 78, 94, 100, 123, 150, 166, 183),
                   Margin = c(0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4))
```

I wish to get the `Margin` at the 1, 2 and 3 minute mark. My anticipated output would therefore look like:

```
MinuteData <- data.frame(Minutes = c(1, 2, 3),
                         Margin = c(0, 2, 4))
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How do you calculate `Margin` in your output?

Comment: @RonakShah I did it manually here, but wish to automate! For example, an eyeball tells me that margin = 0 at 46 seconds and doesn't change until 64 seconds, so at the 1 minute mark, it would be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut`/`findInterval` to divide data in seconds into minutes and select the last value in each minute.

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(Minutes = findInterval(Seconds, seq(0, max(Seconds), 60))) %>%
  summarise(Margin = last(Margin))

#   Minutes Margin
#    <int>  <dbl>
#1       1      0
#2       2      2
#3       3      4
#4       4      4
```

This considers the last value as a new minute, you can remove the last row if you want to consider only complete minutes.

---

This can also be written in base R :

```
with(Data, tapply(Margin, findInterval(Seconds, seq(0, max(Seconds), 60)), 
           function(x) x[length(x)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Minutes = trunc(Seconds / 60) + 1) %>% 
  group_by(Minutes) %>% 
  slice_tail(n = 1)

  Seconds Margin Minutes
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1      46      0       1
2     100      2       2
3     166      4       3
4     183      4       4
```